# Does arguing against rules because they can potentially be broken make any sense?

Tags: argumentation, abortion

Are these two arguments sound?

1. Criminals do not follow laws so Gun Control is pointless.
2. Women will still undergo abortions even if laws restricting abortion are put into place, so laws restricting abortion are pointless.

Comment: Your examples, taken literally, are obvious non-sequiturs, but when such arguments are actually made they are more elaborate, concern specific laws, and rely on additional heuristic assumptions. If you want a substantive answer you'll have to present or link to more realistic versions of these arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting philosophical question hidden somewhere here, but your examples are trivially proven to be unreasonable.

The problem with the first one is that it entirely misses the point of gun control. Gun control consists of *actively* administrating the distribution (and production and modification, etc etc) of firearms, it is not a passive law which merely states "criminals, please don't buy the guns". It doesn't matter whether criminals would actually respect the control or not, their access to guns would still be significantly reduced despite their own opinions of it.

It's the same thing with abortion. Even if you don't respect the law, how are you going to force a doctor to do it at a proper hospital? You'd be forced to have it done by some shady, unauthorized person in an illegal facility, and the risk associated with such a measure is so high that most people are not going to be willing to take that chance, so again, the law will have the intended effect.

But speaking more generally, is there any point to a law which somebody might break, knowing fully well they'll never get caught?

That's a more interesting question, but the answer is probably still yes, these laws have some use, because most people often (wrongly) equate the law with good morals, and people often think that they themselves are morally good, so if you create some law, even if people can choose not to abide by it, many will actually still follow it, simply because they'd want to avoid being criminals, and would like to behave as moral citizens.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying question is one of political philosophy: why societies have regulations, controls and punishment for offenders. It also raises the question of what a "good" and "bad" regulation is. I do not hope to answer or even circumscribe the question.

But if we watch carefully how laws are worded, the lawmakers make an assumption beforehand that their laws will be violated. This can be seen in the clauses of a law that specify enforcement measures (e.g. taken by a court and applied by police) or that specify penalties for offenders (such as reparation of damage, fines or prison).

More specifically:

- For statement 1, we could state that laws are for law-abiding people. Criminals *by definition*, are not law-abiding. Therefore, 'Criminals do not follow gun laws' is a particular case of general statement. In the case of criminals, enforcement and punishment is supposed to do the trick.The problem with this statement, as Coniforld remarks, is that there is a *non sequitur*.
- For statement 2, the problem takes an entirely different dimension and I do **not** see a *non sequitur* there: the problem for women seeking to abort is not always their being unrespectful of law, it is sometimes *necessity*. Hence it begs a legitimate question: what makes an otherwise law-abiding woman go the the *last resort* of violating the law?

In other words, **while it is expected that a criminal will violate the law, the reverse is not necessarily true: a person who violates the law is not necessarily a criminal**. Assuming the second proposition as always true is thus a fallacy.

In this case it could be:

1. that the ethical problem that woman has to solve takes precedence, in her eyes, over the law of society.
2. Or, on an emotional or pain level, necessities of survival do not suffer contradiction.
3. Or it could be many other motives, which one may or may not consider as legitimate.

This preoccupation of fair laws is indeed inscribed in the Preamble of the Universal declaration of human rights:

> Whereas it is essential, if man is not to be compelled to have
>   recourse, as a last resort, to rebellion against tyranny and
>   oppression, that human rights should be protected by the rule of law,

One possible way to go about it could be that a strict prohibition is violating, in a number of cases, **natural law** (which, to paraphrase Montesquieu) is "rooted in the constitution of all human beings". It is obvious that the laws of man are defeated when they violate natural law (a good example would the difficulties of making an economic system without private property, where people would be hoarding or otherwise possessing in secret, or start possessing in fact though not in law).

And indeed, even prohibitionist countries are making allowances for abortion, at least to save the mother from death. If in those countries some women take illegal (and thus dangerous) paths to abortion, then yes, the statement is perfectly sustainable and worthy of attention.

How one *answers* that argument is, however, a different debate.

Answer (score 1):

These arguments are presented out of context.  There are plenty of contexts where they make no sense at all, but in some contexts they can be a reasonable argument.

In many cases, the individual arguing for rules is also arguing that one should ignore all negative externalities to the rules under the logic that the topic at hand (guns, abortion, etc) is more important than everything else, so putting the rules in place is provably better than not using them.  In such cases, the arguments that the rules can be broken are an essential refutation.

In the end, however, such an argument is only a refutation of the *justification* of the rule, not the rule itself.  It is still entirely possible that implementing the rule is a good decision.  It just ensures the pro-rule side's argument is no longer bulletproof.